# Get all posts with help of WP_Query

Tags: wordpress

I need get all posts of site. I try do it in widget, that I made myself, but result is empty.

```
global $post;

$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post_status' => 'publish'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
  while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();
    var_dump($post->ID);
  }
}
```

And when I add in argument array parameter `cat` then return posts, but I need get all posts from all categories, not just from specified categories.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'cat' => 22
);
```

Comment: you can you `get_posts` function https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/

Comment: @Chilll007 get_posts with current `$args` too not return all posts

Comment: try to add `'posts_per_page'   => -1` in your args it will simply returns all posts

Comment: @Chilll007 I writed below that `'posts_per_page' => -1` not helped me

Comment: can you give your full widget code?

Comment: @Chilll007 thank you for your assistance, I found problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood problem, on site (where I working in current time) was installed polylang, and when I specify for function `get_posts` in arguments `'lang' => pll_current_language()` it return all posts for current language.

```
$results = get_posts(
  array(
    'numberposts' => 9999,
    'orderby'     => 'rand',
    'order'       => 'ASC',
    'post_type'   => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'lang'        => pll_current_language()
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `global $post` is in the same function/scope.

If it still not working, instead of `var_dump($post->ID)` try:

```
var_dump($query->post->ID)
```

And don't forget to call `wp_reset_postdata()` after the `while` loop.

Comment: I pointed out that when I specify `cat`, then the data is returned and displayed as they should.

Comment: And I tried `var_dump($query->post->ID)` this too not working without parameter `cat`, but with `cat` parameter work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => -1
        );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        the_title();
        the_content();
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

set **posts_per_page**  to **-1**, this will return all posts from db.

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'post_type'        => 'post',
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: @Aleksar Which are the post_type you are trying to retrieve?

Comment: `'post_type' => 'post'`

Comment: @Aleksar Then this query is fine - Check by disabling all plugins

Comment: yes, I found problem in plugins and wrote problem solution here above